# Reference HTML hyperlink with a field using maptips

Tags: qgis, html, hyperlink, maptips

I'm attempting to make QGIS maptips display a hyperlink as the text from another field in the attribute table. Below are 3 attempts of HTML and the different results.

**When "title documents" is not NULL**

[image]

**When "title documents" is NULL**

[image]

**1**

```
[%case when "title documents" is not NULL then '<a href='||"title documents"||'>' end %]
[%case when "title documents" is not NULL then ' "title no" </a>' else 'Not available' end %]
```

**2**

```
<a href=[%CASE WHEN "title documents" is not null then "title documents"%] > [%"title no"%]</a>
[%CASE WHEN  "title documents" is null then 'Not Available' END%]
```

**3**

```
[%case when "title documents" is not '' then '<a href='||"title documents"||'>' else '' end %]
[%case when "title documents" is not NULL then 'Click Me</a>' else 'Not available' end %]
```

I'm trying to get result 3 but rather than 'Click Me', make it display "title no" which I would have thought code line 1 would achieve but obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert only one QGIS Expression under `[% %]` brackets and play with the `ELSE` clause from `CASE`.

Try the following layer maptips expression :

```sql
[% CASE
  WHEN "title documents" IS NOT NULL
    THEN '<a href="' || "title documents" || '">' || "title no" || '</a>'
  ELSE 'Not available'
END %]
```

Explanation :

Case statement :

```sql
CASE
  WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
  WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
  [ ELSE result_else ]
END
```

The only one condition I set is when the field `"title documents" IS NOT NULL` then display `"title no"` value as a text for a html link with `"title documents"` value as link.

Else, (if `"title documents" IS NULL`) display the text `Not available`.